# How can I find out that if a URL refers to a web page?-using java

Tags: java, url, httpurlconnection

How can I use Java to find out whether a URL refers to a web page or refers to a download link of a file in the internet?

I use the following code to connect to a url:

```
String link = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjNz9zuhczYAhWJoqQKHbGPDLMQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fchannel%2FUC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&usg=AOvVaw3k7TglV_ogkm4gsxKGAESI";
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(link).openConnection());
connection.connect();
```

Should I send a header request? Which header?

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: The `.png` is a pretty good hint.

Comment: A web page and a download link are the thing as far as HTTP is concerned. You're always just downloading stuff. Depending on the stuff's type (usually as specified by its "Content-Type" [header](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField-java.lang.String-), but you're free to infer it however you want), a browser may treat it as HTML and render it it in your window, or it may save it to disk. But the HTTP connection just serves up bytes.

Comment: in other words, you cannot find it out from a header. You need to analyze the url itself to drive some unreliable :-) conclusions.

Comment: Check the first n-bytes and see if there is a <html> tag. Notice that may be not in the begining for some cases (like doctype etc), but most of pages have it.

Comment: The presence of a Content-disposition header in the response is another clue.